# Unity Deferring the Resolution of Objects

Tags: c#, delegates, inversion-of-control, unity-container, constructor-injection

There is an example on MSDN [Deferring the Resolution of Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660854(v=pandp.20).aspx)

```
  // Create a Unity container
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();

// Create an IEnumerable resolver for the IMyClass interface type
var resolver = myContainer.Resolve<Func<IEnumerable<IMyClass>>>();

// ... other code here...

// Register mappings for the IMyClass interface to appropriate concrete types
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyClass, FirstClass>("First");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyClass, SecondClass>("Second");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyClass, ThidClass>("Third");

// Resolve a collection of the mapped target objects
IEnumerable<IMyClass> myClassInstances = resolver();
```

I've inspired a bit and trying to accomplish something like below.

My interface and concrete classes are:

```
public interface IImplementMe
{
    void DoSomething();
}
public class FirstImplementation : IImplementMe
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }
}
public class SecondImplementation : IImplementMe
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second");
    }
}
```

My Service class is like this:

```
public class Service
    {
        private bool someCondition;

        Func<Dictionary<string, IImplementMe>> myClassInstances;
        public Service(Func<Dictionary<string, IImplementMe>> myClassInstances)
        {
            this.myClassInstances = myClassInstances;
        }


        public void Foo()
        {
            if (someCondition)
            {
                myClassInstances.Invoke()["First"].DoSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                myClassInstances.Invoke()["Second"].DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can understand, I am trying to register multiple instances of an interface and shall use the proper one on run time on demand.

How should I register my types, so that I can use them in my service class by giving alias.

I know I can register them by using aliasses and resolve them by giving aliasses. But I don't want to give reference to Unity in my service class.

Or maybe there is a wiser way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is for Unity2.  If you are using Unity3.x, you should use `Lazy<T>` instead of `Func<T>` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec33).  I would question why you need to use deferred resolution as construction of objects should be practically negligible for performance (if it is not, then that is a code smell for too much work being done in your constructors).

Without a reference to Unity, your `Foo` resolved instance will not know the registration names of the collection items.  But you could distinguish the items of the collection in other ways.  You could create a string Name property on IImplementMe.  Or you could get the type of the resolved item.

Comment: You are right I don't have to use deferred resolution. My application is on .Net 4.0 so I have to use Unity2. Actually I am trying to register multiple instances of an interface. In Unity3 you can do this with "container.RegisterTypes" but this extension method does not exist in Unity2.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I could figure out somethig.

Thank you, Tyler..

```
public enum MyType
    {
        First,
        Second
    }

    public interface IImplementMe
    {
        MyType TypeOfClass { get; }
        void DoSomething();
    }
    public class FirstImplementation : IImplementMe
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First");
        }

        public MyType TypeOfClass
        {
            get
            {
                return MyType.First;
            }
        }
    }
    public class SecondImplementation : IImplementMe
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second");
        }

        public MyType TypeOfClass
        {
            get
            {
                return MyType.Second;
            }
        }
    }


    public interface IService { }
    public class Service : IService
    {
        private bool someCondition = true;

        private IImplementMe first;
        private IImplementMe second;
        IEnumerable<IImplementMe> hebele;

        public Service(IEnumerable<IImplementMe> hebele)
        {
            this.hebele = hebele;
            foreach (var item in hebele)
            {
                switch (item.TypeOfClass)
                {
                    case MyType.First:
                        first = item;
                        break;
                    case MyType.Second:
                        second = item;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        public void Foo()
        {
            if (someCondition)
            {
                first.DoSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                second.DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }




class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();


            myContainer.RegisterType<IImplementMe, FirstImplementation>("First");
            myContainer.RegisterType<IImplementMe, SecondImplementation>("Second");
            myContainer.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IImplementMe>, IImplementMe[]>();


            myContainer.RegisterType<IService, Service>();


            var srv = myContainer.Resolve<Service>();
            srv.Foo();
        }
    }
```